# Read dataframe in pandas skipping first column to read time series data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Question is quite self explanatory.Is there any way to read the csv file to read the time series data skipping first column.?
I tried this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("occupancyrates.csv", delimiter = ',')
df = df[:,1:]
print(df)
```

But this is throwing an error:
"TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'"

Comment: Have you tried df.iloc[:,1:]?

Comment: If you know what the column names are, you can use the `usecols` parameter and specify all columns but the first.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Both the above methods worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
df = pd.read_csv("occupancyrates.csv")
df.pop('column_name')
```

dataframe is like a dictionary, where column names are keys & values are the column items. For Ex

```
d = dict(a=1,b=2)
d.pop('a')
```

Now if you print d, the output will be

```
{'b': 2}
```

This is what I have done above to remove a column out of data frame.

By doing this way you need not to assign it back to dataframe like other answer(s)

```
df = df.iloc[:, 1:]
```

Or you don't even need to specify `inplace=True` anywhere

Comment: Please also add some explanation, how can it be helpful or solve the issue.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check & let me know, if there is any query @Saad

Comment: Yes, it is much better

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the column just do:

```
df = pd.read_csv("occupancyrates.csv") # no need to use the delimiter = ','
df = df.drop(['your_column_to_drop'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to delete the **first** column should be:

`del df[df.columns[0]]`

or

`df.pop(df.columns[0])`

Answer (score 0):

If the total no of columns in the CSV file is known, then the `usecols` option of the `read_csv` method can be used in combination with the `range` function.

```py
import pandas as pd

total_cols = 12 #assuming there are 12 columns in the csv file
df = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", usecols=range(1, total_cols))
```